# Inserting a ContentScript Twice on Seperate Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a massive problem in my extension. Basically I have one tab. In this tab I attached with:

```
var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('scripts/tutorial.js'), data.url('scripts/jquery.js')]
});
```

2 scripts. One is named `tutorial.js`, the other is jQuery. This works without any problem. The tutorial script needs jQuery in some functions and can call it.

But now I open another tab and want to do the same thing:

```
var worker2 = tab2.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('scripts/tutorial2.js'), data.url('scripts/jquery.js')]
});
```

So I just changed the tutorial script but want to load the jQuery script again. But that does not work. The debugger just says to me that it does not know what to do with `$`. The tutorial2 script cannot use the jQuery script. So it seems the attaching of jQuery does not work.

How can I solve this? Or is this not possible at all?

Thanks in Advance.

Current Workaround:
Add jQuery to the HTML itself and do the functions in the .html file directly.

Comment: Note that you can now use `./` for `data.ur()l`. E.g. `./scripts/tutorial.js` rather than `data.url('scripts/tutorial2.js')`. It helps to shorten your code. Also you have your scripts the wrong way round, jQuery must load first (by the first in the array)

Comment: Thanks! I will change that.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the scripts in wrong order. If your `tutorial.js` depends on jquery you need to load `jquery.js` first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have tried this and that's not the problem.